# What are these insects in my malt?

Tags: contamination, malt

Bought a bag of malt yesterday at the local homebrew store, and when I opened it today I noticed dark gray to blackish insects in there. I had some unmalted wheat in there with the malts. The store milled the grains for me.

Not sure if I bought them with the malt or if they got in through a hole while the bag was in my kitchen. I'm in Texas, if that matters.

[image: Insects in the malt bag]

Comment: Not a great picture of them, going to make identification hard. Also probably not the right place for this question. I'm not sure such a site exists on the network

Comment: The one on the left looks like the lesser of two weevils.

Comment: If you milled in store before leaving I'd wager they infiltrated once you got home

Comment: While it might be hard to ID from that picture, biology.stackexchange.com has a tag specifically for [species identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're possibly weevils. The one in the middle looks like it has a long 'snout' that weevils tend to have.

Comment: Yes "insects in grain or flour" are usually weevils in my experience - including here in Texas.  Had a bee in my wort yesterday but I think it flew in (at flame out and about to sieve into the fermentation barrel).

Comment: Not just possibly. Those are undoubtedly weevils, almost definitely [grain weevils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_weevil).

Comment: There may be a way to test the hypothesis that these are weevils.  Put one of them on a surface like a table, and give it a nudge.  Apparently, weevils wobble, but they don't fall down!

Answer (score 0):

I bought 20 pounds of flaked barley today, and after getting home I realized that it was loaded with these guys!

So I came on here looking for info about weevils, and found this Q&A in which I myself had commented over 5 years ago.

Well, it's not so funny now that I'm the one with the weevils.  The question here is "what are these insects", but I'm now more interested in finding out what to do about  them!  Maybe I should make a new question.

Comment: Yeah, probably a new question, since stakexchange is really focused on a strict question - answer setup, not like a forum. That said, I'd just extend the protein rest.